# Table: overfull hbox

Tags: tables

when I try to compute the following Latex code I constantly get the "overfull hbox" error. I've tried manually controlling column width using P{xcm} but that doesn't seem to be working for me either. Does anyone know of a robust solution?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|ccccccc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Mechanical Loads}}                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Requirement} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Description}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Engineer} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Location}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{TR Number} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Date Completed} & Pass / Fail \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 1}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 2}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 3}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 4}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 5}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 6}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 7}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 8}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 9}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 10}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 11}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 12}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Test 13}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Brief description} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Example}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{United Kingdom} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               &             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why is every single cell -- other than the header cell -- encased in a `\multicolumn{1}` wrapper?

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, you have got to get rid of the multitude of `\multicolumn{1}` wrappers. Without this fix, nothing else matters. (Aside: Why on earth were these wrappers inserted? Maybe because a bot did the design work??)

Once these wrappers are gone, I'd suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment, set its overall width to `\textwidth`, and allow line-breaking within cells in the six data columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{Mechanical Loads\strut}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l CCCCCC @{}}
\toprule
Req'ment & Description & Engineer & Location & TR Number & Date Completed & Pass\slash Fail \\ 
\midrule
Test 1 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
Test 2 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
\dots \\
%Test 3 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
%Test 4 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
%Test 5 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
%Test 6 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
%Test 7 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
%Test 8 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
%Test 9 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
%Test 10 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
%Test 11 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
%Test 12 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
Test 13 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico, thanks for the response, unfortunately yes I was using a table generator I'm quite new to Latex, I now realize how excessive my code was! Is there a way I can control individual column widths so I can allow for more sentences before the line is broken?

Answer (score 3):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), which a small but complete, compilable document, which reproduce your problem
- Due to lack of it, we haven't any information about your document pages' layout (size of `\textwidth`, which has strong influence on table appearing).
- It seems that you wrote your table with some table generator, which which fill code with unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` vrapers. Remove them!.
- Selected column types as well used `\multicolumn`s not enable to break break text in cells in to (or more) lines, consequently your problem arise.
- You may consider to use ˙tabularray` package for table. Using it a table code is more concise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray,ragged2e}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
%\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
%\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Mechanical Loads\strut}
\begin{tblr}{colsep=1pt,
             colspec = {@{} l 
                        *{6}{X[m, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                                  cmd=\Centering\hspace{0pt}]} @{}}
            }
\toprule
Req'ment & Description & Engineer & Location & TR Number & Date Completed & Pass\slash Fail \\
\midrule
Test  1 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ 
Test  2 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\ 
Test  3 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
Test  4 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
Test  5 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
Test  6 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
Test  7 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
Test  8 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
Test  9 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
Test 10 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
Test 11 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
Test 12 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
Test 13 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom &  &  & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, here's a recommended reading [tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).
Second of all, don't use table generators!
Frankly, ChatGPT can produce much cleaner code for simple tables like yours.
Anyway, the link leads to content, after reading which you should be able to create this and even more complicated tables without much help.

Based on your example, the table is too wide and doesn't fit within a page.
Out of many solutions, I think you could make two groups and stack them together or rotate and render the table vertically (see the sections below).
You should also use captions instead of extra top headers, which can be formatted if you wish;
e.g. in codes below, uncomment lines of `\DeclareCaption...` and lines inside `\captionsetup` to make the caption bold but I wouldn't recommend it.

If cells are too wide, `p{}`-type column creates paragraph-like cells and add line breaks if necessary. Also see [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682726/31283)'s answer for example of using `X`-type for unified columns.
Alternatively, it's possible to add line breaks manually with convenient macros such as `\thead` for headers or `\makecell` for regular cells.
In both cases `\\` is accepted but both macros require additional `makecell` package.
On top of that, `\Gape` in the last headers increase row height to add more space for headers (also requires `makecell` package).

**Rotate**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}

% \DeclareCaptionTextFormat{bold-text}{\bfseries#1}
% \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bold-label}{\bfseries\bothIfFirst{#1~}{}#2}
\captionsetup[table]{
  position=top,
  skip=3pt,
  % textformat=bold-text,
  % labelformat=bold-label,
}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\theadgape}{\Gape[0pt][0pt]}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \centering
  \caption{Mechanical Loads}\label{tab:mech-loads-v}
  \begin{tabular}{l *6{c}}
    \hline
    \thead{Requirement}
    & \thead{Description} & \thead{Engineer} & \thead{Location}
    & \thead{TR\\Number} & \thead{Date\\Completed} & \thead{\Gape[10pt]{Pass/Fail}} \\
    \hline
    Test 1  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 2  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 3  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 4  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 5  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 6  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 7  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 8  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 9  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 10 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 11 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 12 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    Test 13 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

**Split into groups**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}

% \DeclareCaptionTextFormat{bold-text}{\bfseries#1}
% \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bold-label}{\bfseries\bothIfFirst{#1~}{}#2}
\captionsetup[table]{
  position=top,
  skip=3pt,
  % textformat=bold-text,
  % labelformat=bold-label,
}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\theadgape}{\Gape[0pt][0pt]}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \centering
  \caption{Mechanical Loads}\label{tab:mech-loads-h}
  \begin{tabular}{l *3{c}}
    \hline
    \thead{Requirement}
    & \thead{Description} & \thead{Engineer} & \thead{\Gape[10pt]{Location}} \\
    \hline
    Test 1  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 2  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 3  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 4  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 5  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 6  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 7  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 8  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 9  & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 10 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 11 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 12 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    Test 13 & Brief description & Example & United Kingdom \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \thead{Requirement}
    & \thead{TR\\Number} & \thead{Date\\Completed} & \thead{\Gape[9pt]{Pass/Fail}} \\
    \hline
    Test 1  & & & \\
    Test 2  & & & \\
    Test 3  & & & \\
    Test 4  & & & \\
    Test 5  & & & \\
    Test 6  & & & \\
    Test 7  & & & \\
    Test 8  & & & \\
    Test 9  & & & \\
    Test 10 & & & \\
    Test 11 & & & \\
    Test 12 & & & \\
    Test 13 & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

| Rotate | Split |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |